# 'request' - undeclared identifier, why am I getting this error?

Tags: mql5

I believe I am doing the exact same as in the MQl5 guide, 820 and 1517.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
//--- Preparing the request 
double BuyAsync(double volume)
   {MqlTradeRequest request={};
      request.price        =     SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol(),SYMBOL_ASK);   // Long
      request.magic        =     EXPERT_MAGIC;                 // EA magic number so you can track trades 
      request.action       =     TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;            // Market order
      request.symbol       =     "EURUSD";                     // Symbol 
      request.type         =     ORDER_TYPE_BUY;               // Long
      request.order        =     "OrderTicketBuy";             // The orderticket so you can trace the individual trade 
      request.deviation    =     5;                            // Maximum price deviation 
      request.volume       =     0.25;                         // This should be €25.000 
      request.tp           =     tpLong;                       // Take profit long 
      request.sl           =     slLong;                       // Stoploss long
      request.comment      =     "Buy using OrderSendAsync()";
   MqlTradeResult result={};
   if(!OrderSendAsync(request,result))
     {
      Print(__FUNCTION__,": error ", GetLastError(),", retcode = ", result.retcode);
     }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
MqlTradeRequest request={};
```

use this:

```
MqlTradeRequest request;
```

do same for the request

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. But this also doesn't work, gives the same errors as before.

Comment: let me try again

Comment: are you sure that all of your variables are well declared

Comment: Even for variables that don't need to be defined, like the number 5 at request.deviation, it gives the same error.

Comment: one mistake in ur code is _Symbol(), it should be _Symbol and also u are adding request.symbol as "EURUSD" but u can put _Symbol, which will make the program better, _Symbol is the value of symbol u r watching

Comment: while sending order you don't need request.order so remove that, it is only used for closing a trade

Comment: i don't know if you want to use request only, but i m executing trade by using Trade.mqh, i can share you about it

Comment: Thanks! And it would be great if you could share "Trade.mqh" I have been trying to find a way to send orders. But it hasn't been going great...

Comment: check out my latest answer, i understand your pain, i struggled alot at first

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Trade\Trade.mqh>

CTrade trade;

void OnInit()


{
double vol=0.01;
double selling_price=SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_BID);
double buying_price=SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_ASK);
trade.Sell(vol,_Symbol,selling_price,0,0);
trade.Buy(vol,_Symbol,buying_price,0,0);
}
```

this is just a simple example, i haven't used stop loss of take profit, i have just opened the trade u can modify the stop loss and take profit.Hope my effort makes a difference for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help! I will definitely try this! MQL5 is so frustrating sometimes ;)

Comment: you are welcome, hoping for your positive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, this is the answer to the original question:

```
//--- Preparing the request 
void BuyAsync()
   {MqlTradeRequest request={};
      request.price        =     SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_ASK);   // Long
      request.magic        =     EXPERT_MAGIC;                 // EA magic number so you can track trades 
      request.action       =     TRADE_ACTION_DEAL;            // Market order
      request.symbol       =     _Symbol;                      // Symbol 
      request.type         =     ORDER_TYPE_BUY;               // Long
      request.order        =     "OrderTicketBuy";             // The orderticket so you can trace the individual trade 
      request.deviation    =     5;                            // Maximum price deviation 
      request.volume       =     0.25;                         // This should be €25.000 
      request.tp           =     tpLong;                       // Take profit long 
      request.sl           =     slLong;                       // Stoploss long
      request.comment      =     "Buy using OrderSendAsync()";
   MqlTradeResult result={};
   if(!OrderSendAsync(request,result))
     {
      Print(__FUNCTION__,": error ", GetLastError(),", retcode = ", result.retcode);
     }
```

The difference is in the first couple of lines.